# How to set discount only in some line item's price added to cart?

Tags: commerce, rules

I need to achieve a discount on a Drupal site with Commerce through rules.

**Event** :
  When you have to decide a product price [ Calculating the sell price of a product ]

**Conditions** :
  If the logged user have role 'role to trigger'
  and there are at least 2 products in the cart with product_type = 'magazine' 
  and field_mag_type == 'tipo'

**Action** :
  Take the products with field_mag_type == 'tipo' in the cart and discount it by 15% [amount * 0.75]

Can someone did something like this and want to help me?

For now I have this rule

```
{ "rules_sconto_riviste_multiple" : {
    "LABEL" : "Sconto riviste multiple",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "REQUIRES" : [
      "rules",
      "commerce_cart",
      "commerce_order",
      "commerce_line_item",
      "commerce_product_reference"
    ],
    "ON" : [ "commerce_product_calculate_sell_price" ],
    "IF" : [
      { "user_has_role" : {
          "account" : [ "site:current-user" ],
          "roles" : { "value" : { "6" : "6" } },
          "operation" : "OR"
        }
      },
      { "entity_has_field" : { "entity" : [ "commerce-line-item" ], "field" : "commerce_product" } },
      { "component_rules_product_is_magazine" : { "product" : [ "commerce-line-item:commerce-product" ] } },
      { "commerce_order_is_cart" : { "commerce_order" : [ "site:current-cart-order" ] } },
      { "commerce_order_contains_product_type" : {
          "commerce_order" : [ "site:current-cart-order" ],
          "product_type" : { "value" : { "magazine" : "magazine" } },
          "operator" : "\u003E=",
          "value" : "2"
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "commerce_line_item_unit_price_multiply" : {
          "commerce_line_item" : [ "commerce_line_item" ],
          "amount" : ".75",
          "component_name" : "discount",
          "round_mode" : "1"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

This rule work fine but the field_mag_type == 'tipo'  check is missing because I don't know how to check a field in all products in the cart and count if they are > 2.

If I can't solve this I'm bound to clone the 'magazine' product type and add a new one with the same fields.. but I want to avoid it..

Answer (score 1):

You should use the *Calculating the sell price of a product* event instead of the add to cart event.

The use case you are trying to implement is actually discussed in the [commerce users guide](http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/sell-price-calculation). If you fail to make your rule work after going through the documentation, then please update your question with the exported rule.

Comment: In this users guide I do not find a solution to this issues. I readed it before write here. For now I didn't figure how to solve this.. I can export the rule I wrote but is not working like I want..

Comment: @Shyghar: Please export it nevertheless and post it in your question. Like this it is possible for other people to take a close look at it.